# BigQuery: Can a query job run on a table while another query job manipulates the table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I update a table in regular intervals by overwriting the whole table. However, I also run SELECT queries on that table often. My question is what if I am currently running the query overwriting the table, and I also attempt to run a SELECT query on the table while it is being updated/overwritten? What about the other way around, I am SELECTing from that table but the regular job overwriting the table starts at the same time. Is there any point in time when the table cannot be read/only partially read, or where the table cannot be overwritten? I need to be 100% sure that the SELECT query will always work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run a `SELECT` statement over a table, and it will never reflect a partially-modified state. `SELECT`ing from a table does not prevent running queries that modify it, either. If you use DML to modify a table, [note the limitations from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language):

> Only the following combinations of DML statements are allowed to run concurrently on a table:
>
> - UPDATE and INSERT
> - DELETE and INSERT
> - INSERT and INSERT
>
> Otherwise, one of the DML statements will be aborted. For example, if two UPDATE statements execute simultaneously against the table then only one of them will succeed.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, if I start the SELECT statement before starting to overwrite the table, it will SELECT from the 'old' table? And if I start the SELECT statement while the table is in the process of being overwritten, it will also SELECT from the 'old' table?